# How to get colord to install ICC profile when no devices detected?

Tags: linux, centos, screen, calibration, color-management

I currently have a problem calibrating monitors on centos7. 
Using gnome or kde, I cannot properly use the color settings to apply a newly created ICC profile. The devices tab has not display listed (only a printer installed).

After some reading I found that **colord** uses **xrandr** to detect displays and they should appear with the following call:

```
$ colormgr get-devices
```

This does not bring any display devices (only the printer mentioned earlier).
When I use xrandr I properly get my list of displays:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94
```

Does anyone knows why this problem occurs and how I could work around it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've updated to cent7.4 recently and colorgr seems to bring the correct result now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post.. nonetheless:

I get this kind of behaviour when I'm messing with colord, such as trying to restart the server.  The behaviour usually goes away with a reboot (whereby colord is restarted correctly.)

If this is happening with a fresh boot/login, then I would check to verify that colord is installed correctly.